# How to register a Java Object in the JxBrowser before first JavaScript

Tags: jxbrowser

I am using JxBrowser 6.1.1 and succeed in registering a Java object in the `JsContext` in a `onFinishLoadingFrame` handler. The problem is that the property is not yet available when the first `JavaScript` is run in the page loaded by the JxBrowser.

The working call looks like this:

browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue("window").asObject().setProperty("api", api);

When I do the same in the new `onScriptContextCreated` handler, the program halts executing:

```
JSValue jsWindow = browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue("window");
```

The full code is and fails at line JSValue jsWindow = ...:

```
    client.browser.addScriptContextListener(new ScriptContextAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onScriptContextCreated(ScriptContextEvent event) {
            Browser browser = event.getBrowser();
            JSValue jsWindow = browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue("window");
            JSObject windowObject = jsWindow.asObject();
            windowObject.setProperty("api", client.getApi());
        }
    });
```

I guess the `window` property is simply not there yet.

Is there a way to achieve this with the `onScriptContextCreated` event or is there a different way to achieve this?

The code also works fine when started in a separate thread as proposed below. But the problem remains that this code runs later than the first JavaScript in the browser.

```
           Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                  JSValue jsWindow = browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue("window");
                  JSObject windowObject = jsWindow.asObject();
                  windowObject.setProperty("api", client.getApi());

               }
           });
           thread.start();
```

Comment: I used the same line `browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue("window").asObject().setProperty("api", api);` in `onScriptContextCreated` method but everything worked as expected. Consider adding complete code or any output.

Comment: Where do you use it? In onScriptContextCreated? The problem is that there is no error at all, it just hags. In the debugger the browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue("window") is the last to be executed.

Comment: yes i used it in `onScriptContextCreated` and the program didn't hang. Put all of your code, it may help.

Comment: I added a longer code snippet above. The browser also hangs when I try to execute Javascript to log to the browser console,

Comment: I hope i could reproduce the problem but no luck :(  Try creating a thread inside `onScriptContextCreated` and put the code inside `runnable` and watch the logs.

Comment: When running in a separate thread it works fine. Still the thread is slower than the first script to run in the page and thus the api is not present yet. I add the code to run in a thread above too. I also do not see any error messages.